# Cant Read Resource

Tags: java, resources, getresource

I am trying to read a **.class* resource from a package. I am using the following code to achieve this...

```
URL path = SomeClass.class.getResource("/source/someClass.class");
```

When I run this code, I end up with `path = null;`. However, if I use the same code and try to access other resources such as **.gif* and **.txt* files, it is successful. Is there a reason why I can't access the **.class* files?

Comment: URLs in Jars are case sensitive. Make sure the file is not named SomeClass.java instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be resource  path is incorrect. Because the class directory is special to project.

You can try the following:

```
URL path = SomeClass.class.getResource("PackagePath/someClass.class");
```

the PackagePath  like  "/com/xxx/projectTest".

Answer (score 0):

Re-read the javadoc.  I think it describes the two ways you can use getResource():

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

Try the following:

```
URL path = Class.getResource( "modified/package/SomeClass" )
```

You might want to use:

```
InputStream stream = Class.getResourceAsStream("modified/package/SomeClass")
```

since you are only trying to copy class files into a Jar file.

Comment: I tryed next : URL url = Class.getResource(".package.SomeClass") - not work.

Comment: You did it wrong.  That's why it didn't work.  Use Class.getResource("package/SomeClass").  The javadoc states you must replace the '.'in a fully qualified classname with '/'.